# Change zoom level Google Maps Api v2 on app start

Tags: android, google-maps, zooming, google-maps-android-api-2

Is it possible to change the zoom level as soon as the map is ready? When I open the app it shows the map and the blue dot for my location. However, the zoom level is the default 3. How can I change this? I know how to do it when the 'MyLocationButton'is clicked but not when the app starts.

This is my class

```
public class MainPhoneActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationSource, LocationListener, OnMyLocationButtonClickListener, OnMapReadyCallback{

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private OnLocationChangedListener mMapLocationListener = null;

    // location accuracy settings
    private static final LocationRequest REQUEST = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_phone);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.mapView);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        map.setLocationSource(this);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);
    }

    public void showMyLocation(View view) {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            String msg = "Location = "
                    + LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (mMapLocationListener != null) {
            mMapLocationListener.onLocationChanged(location);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, REQUEST,this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        // Do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        // Do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void activate(OnLocationChangedListener onLocationChangedListener) {
        mMapLocationListener = onLocationChangedListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void deactivate() {
        mMapLocationListener = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set zoom level like following:

```
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(point,15));
```

Where `point` is your `LatLng` position. In this way you can center the map in that point with given zoom level.

Complete method:

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        map.setLocationSource(this);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);
        //newLatLngZoom(LatLng , ZoomLevel) -> choose your zoom level
        // and change my 'point' with yours
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(point,15));
    }
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to get the dot coords, you can try this:

```
Location loc = map.getMyLocation();
LatLng point = new LatLng(loc.getlatitude() , loc.getLongitude());
```

and use that point as center.

Complete method:

```
@Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
            map.setLocationSource(this);
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            map.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);
            Location loc = map.getMyLocation();
            if(loc != null){
                LatLng point = new LatLng(loc.getLatitude() , loc.getLongitude());
                map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(point,15));
            }
        }
```

This could cause a `NullPointerException` beacuse `loc` could be null.

**OTHER SOLUTION**

If you want to get only first time the coordinates, you should work in `onLocationChanged`, using a boolean variable to set first call.

Declare it `CRDS_CALL = false;`

```
  @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if (mMapLocationListener != null) {
                mMapLocationListener.onLocationChanged(location);
                if(!CRDS_CALL){
                    LatLng point = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLognitude());
                    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(point,15));
                    CRDS_CALL = true;
                }
        }
    }
```

In this answer i use `map`, but you have to use your `mapFragment`, but if you want to use it in other methods over `onCreate`, you have to declare outside of it.

Add this just before the `onCreate`

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
```

And inside it, use it like follwing:

```
mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.mapView);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

In that way, you can use `mapFragment` in other methods

Comment: This, I think, is the easiest way, and could go inside the method `onMapReady(GoogleMap)`

Comment: Right, i update my answer with that method implementations ;) Thanks

Comment: I thought it was something like this but my problem is getting the LatLng position on app start. It works when I do it in the OnLocationChanged but I have no idea how to get the LatLng from the blue dot that is shown initially

Comment: Thanks for that. When I use this I get this error
'Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference'

Can it be that it has something to do with the order of my code?

Comment: No the order is correct, probably the coordinates are not got yet. I've updated my answer with another attempt. Hope it helps (once again ;-) )

Comment: Thanks so much for your effort. Only problem now is that 'map' cannot be resolved in onLocationChanged.

Comment: You have to declare mapFragment as a global variable. I'm updating my answer

Comment: Still the NullPointerException. I'll just keep figuring out what to and will post the solution when I find it. Thanks ever so much for all your help!

Comment: You're welcome! Keep in mind that if you use the solution given using onLocationChanged, you have to use only that! So you must delete the code that i've written in onMapReady! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

The solution was to do everything @MikeKeepsOnShine said but remove the

```
   Location loc = map.getMyLocation();
        LatLng point = new LatLng(loc.getLatitude() , loc.getLongitude());
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(point,15));
```

part from onMapReady. Works absolutely perfectly now!

Answer (score 1):

You should use [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory.html#zoomTo(float)). And you should put this request in onMapReady() callback. Something like this:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    map.setLocationSource(this);
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14), 2000, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have already done the new "MapAsync" way so you are one step forward to the result.
In order to zoom, you can use the animateCamera method for googleMap object to zoom to a specific location:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#animateCamera(com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate)
for example, a zoomin:

```
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
```

or if you already know "where":

```
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(knownlocation,17));
```

and you will be very close to the location.
If you need to do at the first "locationUpdate" you should keep a flag to false and set to true the first time you receive a location, at that time you perform the zoom to location.

EDIT: If you want to zoom only the first time, where you receive location updates (which is not really clear from your code), you can do, assuming you have a class variable like:

```
private boolean FIRST_TIME = true;
```

the following code:

```
if(FIRST_TIME){
myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location,17));
FIRST_TIME = false;
}
```

The best option is to remove the listener but it seems you use location updates as "blue dot" updates.

Comment: Can you please explain how to do this? I've been trying everything I know but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was:

```
 mMap.setMinZoomPreference(6.0f);
 mMap.setMaxZoomPreference(20.0f);
```

You can modify the zoom preference values to your taste.